# Why can't I rewrite a list in a user-define function?

Tags: python, function, user-defined

I am going to rewrite a list in a user-defined function, simply using the name of itself, rather than any built-in list function, but it doesn't work.

Using built-in functions(.append, del, etc) to mutate the list does work, but I still wonder why rewriting doesn't work. I simplify my code to show the main problem.

```
def function(y):
    y=y[:3]  # Rewrite the list
    return y


y=[0,1,2,3,4]
function(y)
print(y)
```

expected: `[0,1,2]`
actual: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: "Why" questions are usually not a good fit for StackOverflow. The language works the way it does, because that's how it was designed. It's hard to answer beyond that.

Comment: @CalebGoodman You shouldn't. Did you perhaps write `y = function(y)` instead? Or if you tried it statement by statement at the interpreter prompt, the `function(y)` line will produce `[0, 1, 2]` because the function `return`s that value, but the subsequent `print` will show `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` because, as OP describes, the global `y` has not been modified.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I modified the original code slightly without realized that it would change the results, and I deleted that comment after realizing

Comment: Anyway, I recommend reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3):

In fact the y in function and the y in the main function happen to have the same name, but are not the same variable, the are just a reference to the same object. but as soon as you make an assignment to y in the function you crate a new object

In order to make this more clear I renamed y in function() into yy

```
def function(yy):
    yy=yy[:3]  # Rewrite the list
    return yy


y=[0,1,2,3,4]
y = function(y) # here I assign the result of the function call to y
print(y)
```

Now A second solution, which might confuse you as it seems to contradict what I said before.

```
def function(yy):
    yy[:]=yy[:3]  # Rewrite the list

y=[0,1,2,3,4]
function(y) # here nothing is assigned. function directly modifies the passed object
print(y)
```

In fact following code in function
`y = y[:3]`  creates a new list, that contains the first three elements of y and assigns it to a variable, that will be called y, but which is a new object.

The code `y[:] = y[:3]` says to keep the same object y, but to replace all of its elements with the first three elements of y.

So again previous code, but now with debug prints:

```
def function(y):
    print("The id of y is ", id(y))
    y=y[:3]  # Rewrite the list
    print("The id of y is ", id(y)) # you created a new object
    return y


y=[0,1,2,3,4]
print("The id of y is ", id(y))
y = function(y) # here I assign the result of the function call to y
print(y)
print("The id of y is ", id(y))  # you got a new object, that is no stored in y
```

And now the other code with debug prints:
    def function(y):
        print("The id of y is ", id(y))
        y[:]=y[:3]  # Rewrite the list
        print("The id of y is ", id(y))

```
y=[0,1,2,3,4]
print("The id of y is ", id(y))
function(y) # here nothing is assigned. function directly modified the passed object
print("The id of y is ", id(y))
print(y)
```